# tabBar default and custom image aligned

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, imageicon, uitabbaritem

I have a problem with the Apple Tab Bar. 
I created a tab bar with defaults and customs images. [image]

so here ( this is the storyboard) looks quite good but when I run the simulator this happens:
[image]

customs images are not aligned centered and I can't find a solution for that. I tried a lot of alignments but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you try changing the `Content Mode` of `TabBar` to `center` or `scaleAspectFit`?

Comment: Yes, tried both but nothing changes

Comment: @EricAya the code I'm using is Swift, and to modify the tabBar ( not in the storyboard ) you need to use Swift and not objective-C

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this problem, because you may be using a high-resolution image, when iOS is looking for a standard resolution image.

iOS automatically selects the appropriate image size for you, depending on the resolution of the accessing device. Set a "Standard Resolution" image, for non-retina devices, and a "High Resolution" image, for retina displays.

> Use all custom icons with same square size with size(square with width & height) of 30, 60 90 for 1x, 2x & 3x respectively.

Here Apple document: **[Tab Bar Icon Size](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/)**

In portrait orientation, tab bar icons appear above tab titles. In landscape orientation, the icons and titles appear side-by-side. Depending on the device and orientation, the system displays either a regular or compact tab bar. Your app should include custom tab bar icons for both sizes.

[image]

Comment: Size of icons? Are those 30, 60 & 90 respectively ?

Comment: maybe if I share to you the screen?

Comment: What does it even mean? When do you get a Compact Tab Bar? And what are you supposed to do when somebody rotates your application?

Comment: what is difference between squre glyphs vs circular glyphs?